# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Unirest\Exception: Bad URL

Tags: php, api, url, unirest

I'm trying to request a REST API using PHP Unirest.
The printed error is the following:

> Bad URL, colon is first character

And my code:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

use Unirest\Request as UniRequest;
use CurlFile;

if (isset($_POST['primeiro'])) {
    $where = $_POST["where"];
    $equal = $_POST["equal"];

    $resultado = new pedidos;
    $valores = $resultado->LogIgualA($where, $equal);
}

class pedidos {
    function LogIgualA($where, $equal) {
        $wsURL = "localhost:8080/public";

        try {
            $valores = UniRequest::get($wsURL."/visual/json_log/where=".$where."/equal=".$equal, $headers, null);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

        $valoresAux = $valores->body;

        $valores = [];

        foreach($valoresAux as $z){
            $ID = $z->ID;
            $DateConnection = $z->DateConnection;
            $TimeToServe = $z->TimeToServe;
            $ClientIP = $z->ClientIP;
            $CacheCode = $z->CacheCode;
            $Bytes = $z->Bytes;
            $Method = $z->Method;
            $RequestProtocol = $z->RequestProtocol;
            $RequestIP = $z->RequestIP;
            $RequestPort = $z->RequestPort;
            $RequestFolder = $z->RequestFolder;
            $Auth = $z->Auth;
            $RouteLeft = $z->RouteLeft;
            $RouteRight = $z->RouteRight;
            $ContentType = $z->ContentType;
        }

        return $valores;
    }
}
```

The "isset($_POST['primeiro']" is when I click the button in HTML so it calls the function in PHP.
I really don't know how to use this...

Comment: Where/when do you get that error message? Btw, is the URL really `localhost:8080/public/public/....`? and then `.../json_log/where=something/equal=something`? That looks pretty strange.

Comment: no, i have changed now, but the error presists

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the URL format is correct? That you're not suppose to send in a query string for `where` and `equal`? Either way, you should [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) those variables before putting them into the URL.

Comment: 100% I'm not. but I know I have to send the parms in the url. Can I do this? `$valores = $resultado->LogIgualA(urlencode($where), urlencode($equal));`

Comment: He means: `UniRequest::get($wsURL."/visual/json_log/where=".urlencode($where)."/equ.........`

Comment: well... the same error, I also tried on the `$wsURL` and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prepend a protocol like `https://`.

There are other people having the same issue where prepending the protocol fixed this... https://github.com/Azure/doAzureParallel/issues/44

URL is not http: `localhost:8080/public`

Also check that there is no malicious input in your `$_POST` vars and maybe you need to use `urlencode()` on the fields containing appropriate characters.

Comment: That would be a pretty awful error message, if that is the issue. Not saying that it isn't the issue, just an observation. :-)

Comment: the "static" part of the URL is "localhost:8080/public". And if I add the http:// it loads infinitely